# How can I have my python webdriver refresh a page until a dropdown menu appears with an option I need to be selected?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I currently have this, a script that selects an option in an already present dropdown menu. I need the script to refresh a page until a dropdown menu appears with the option that I need to be selected.

Comment: I don't see any code.. You say "I currently have this" without ever showing us what "this" is. This question also shows no attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an endless loop which you would exit once you have the desired option selected:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

DESIRED_OPTION = "My desired option"

while True:
    dropdown_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "#dropdownID")))
    dropdown = Select(dropdown_element)

    selected_option = dropdown.first_selected_option.text
    print("Selected option is '%s'" % selected_option)
    if selected_option == DESIRED_OPTION:
        break

    driver.refresh()
```

This code assumes that your dropdown is represented via `select`->`option`.